# Two views with one html

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a list in my html and a view to append list items on it.  Now If I click on the list header there should be a popup which should display the same list items on it.  I have created a view for the list items display and inside the same view I am creating a click event and rendering the same view with different el for pop up.  Everything works good, I can see the list item header inside the popup, but the list items, I am adding it dynamically.  Those list items getting appended to the old list items, not in the new popup.  Can some one help me with this.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" >
    <ul id="Listid" data-role="collapsible-set" ></ul>
</div>
```

View:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
         _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    }

    render: function(){ 
        $(this.el).html($(Template).html());
    }

    event: {
        'click #header':  'popup'
    }

    listing: function(){
        $("#Listid").append("<li id='listid1'> </li>");
    }

    popup: function(){
        this.view2 = new view ({el: popupel});
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please add what is your popupel ?

Comment: Its the el for the popup page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will solve your problem,

```
listing: function(){
   this.find('#Listid').append("<li id='listid1'></li>")
}
```

Comment: can you share any jsfiddle link?

Comment: Saravanan, I tried but its not working.  I want a list of items in one container and if I click on the container header, a popup should open and it should display the same list of items.  The ul for the list of items is in html page, but the lists are getting added dynamically....

Comment: I did the popup function in the main page and created a if else to select the two views...and it worked...Thanks.